# Change background color of Tkinter window in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, themes

I am using the function `tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()` to ask the user to choose a file path. The problem is that, due to a dark theme I am using, the text is light grey. The background of the window should be black (it is black in the rest of the system), but for some reason in the tkinter window it remains white. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

As you can see, the text is barely readable.

I tried to change the color of the background of the window using `.configure(background='black')` but with no success... can anybody help?

Thank you very much!

Edit: alternatively, I would also be happy to change the color of the text to black... just not light grey on white!

Comment: What operating system are you on?

Comment: @Mike-SMT Debian 8

Comment: It is possible the issue is related to a them on your operating system. I know for windows at least tkinter get a lot of its theme from windows and the same can probably be said for other OS's as well. Have you tried to change the theme of your OS yet?

Comment: @Mike-SMT yes, of course changing the theme works, but this doesn't solve the issue. I would like that my python script would be usable also on a computer with a dark theme.

Comment: I understand what you want I just wanted to make sure the issue was related to tkinter grabbing the theme from the OS.

Comment: Yes, I think that tkinter is grabbing the text colour from the theme but not the window background.

Answer (score 0):

From the source code in tkinter I do not see any options that allow for the background to be changed for `askopenfilename()`.

From the code:

```
# For the following classes and modules:
#
# options (all have default values):
#
# - defaultextension: added to filename if not explicitly given
#
# - filetypes: sequence of (label, pattern) tuples.  the same pattern
#   may occur with several patterns.  use "*" as pattern to indicate
#   all files.
#
# - initialdir: initial directory.  preserved by dialog instance.
#
# - initialfile: initial file (ignored by the open dialog).  preserved
#   by dialog instance.
#
# - parent: which window to place the dialog on top of
#
# - title: dialog title
#
# - multiple: if true user may select more than one file
#
# options for the directory chooser:
#
# - initialdir, parent, title: see above
#
# - mustexist: if true, user must pick an existing directory
#
```

Comment: I tried it (I had to change it a bit) and I still have the dialog with white background... thank you very much for your help BTW

Comment: Ok. there is another option for messabox that will change its font you might be able to use a font object to edit the font. `root.option_add('*Dialog.msg.font', 'Helvetica 12')` replace `Helvetica 12` with a font object from tkinters `Font.font()`. I will try to test this more when I get home. I have linux at home. If you can update a messagebox this way it might be possible to do the same to `askopen`. I will see what I can find.

Comment: @FrancescoBoccardo sorry to say I do not believe you can do much about this. I have updated my answer with the reason.

Comment: @FrancescoBoccardo you would need to create your own customer `askopenfile()` window using `Toplevel()`. This might be a little complicated but could prove fruitful.

Comment: Hmm. That sounds like a bug of tkinter to me... Why is it not correctly getting all the theme colors? Anyhow, thank you very much for your time and your help, Mike!

Comment: @FrancescoBoccardo It might be a bug if it is getting the theme of the font and color of text but not the background. However I can't say for sure as I do know that many of tkinters built in features like this have very specific design rules to follow that cannot be altered. I do know that for windows many of the configurable features you have in linux do not work on windows so I will have to test some more when I get home. I would love to find something that will work here. It has potential to be useful for other methods as well.